Mongo db command find requires authentication
With node js i connect to mongo db.
I have user created in database and security enabled on mongo db conf file.
    mongoose
      .connect(
        "mongodb://user:password@domain:27017/database?authSource=admin"
      )
      .then(() => {
        console.log("connected to mongodb");
        httpServer.listen(4001, () => {
          console.log("API is listening on port 4001");
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error connecting to MongoDB:", error);
      });

The above throws: command find requires authentication. It fails to authenticate on mongo.
But if i do directly in the command line:
    mongosh "mongodb://user:password@domain:27017/database?authSource=admin"

It connects without problem.
node js version 20.14.0
i tried everything i read about.
Lots of stuff without success.

Did you grant any roles to the user?

.connect is very unlikely to case "command find requires authentication", can you narrow down which line of code is problematic?

Does this answer your question? How to solve 'command find requires authentication' using Node.js and mongoose?
